# How to update the data of the selected row in datagridview?

Tags: sql, visual-studio

This is my code:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(global::Registro_Elettronico_Reperti.Properties.Settings.Default.Registro_RepertiConnectionString);

string sql = "UPDATE Registro_Reperti SET [Ritirato da]='" + cbox_competenza.Text + "', Operatore='" + txt_operatore.Text + "', PerID= '" + txt_perid + "', Ritirato = 'Si' WHERE Id=?????";

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand exeSql = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, connection);
connection.Open();

exeSql.ExecuteNonQuery();

MessageBox.Show("Operazione completata", "Messaggio", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

How to get the id of the row in the `WHERE` clause??

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i rewrote the code using the parameters. Can you tell me how to set the WHERE dial so that pressing the button updates only the selected row?